# What is the different when we using state and reducer in mapStateToProps. What is the correct method?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have seen that lot of tutorials were using this method in their mapStateToProps method.

**(state.ReducerName)**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    invoices: state.IcmWebReducer,
 }
};
```

But this didn't work for me. What was working for me was this

**(state.objectParameterName)**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    params: state.params,
    invoices: state.invoices
 }
};
```

My reducer as below

```
const initialState = {
invoices : [],
params: {
    status: 'Pending',
    _sort: 'documentInfo.dueDate',
    _order: 'desc',
    q: ''
 }
};

const IcmWebReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
switch (action.type){
    case 'UPDATE_INVOICES':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            invoices: action.invoices
        });
    case 'UPDATE_PARAMS':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            params: action.params
        });
    default:
        return state;
 }
};

export default IcmWebReducer;
```

What is the correct method ? What is the different between this ?

Comment: Where did you see the first case? It should be different than yours. You probably have one single root reducer and state, so `state.parms` and `state.invoices` work here. But, for multiple reducers hence multiple states, for example, you will have `state.icmWebState` and `state.otherState` and you'll get the properties like `state.icmWebState.params` and so on.

Comment: Yes i am not using multiple reducers. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(state.objectParameterName)` is the correct method.

`mapStateToProps` is for using the redux state as props in the `connected` component. The reducer is a pure function, it just takes some value and returns it. The reducer updates and returns the states based upon the action type fired.
Even if you somehow define the reducer in the redux state and try to use it, it's a wrong practice.

Comment: In addition to what @kreysix have explained, [`mapStateToProps: state => stateProps`]: state changes => mapStateToProps runs => stateProps changes => component re-render. So for more performance, be sure that the stateProps contains just the state you need in your component. to simply it: if you have a state like so `post: {id: 1, title: 'test', value: 'testValue', x: 'x', y: 'y', z: 'z'}` And in your component you just need the id, title and value of your post state, so be sure that the stateProps of your component contains just those tree and not the whole post object.